# How to expose API over AWS ALB for receiving zip files

Tags: amazon-web-services, go

I have an external client (non-AWS) that wants to send data (zipped files) to my S3 bucket. I do not want to share any temporary IAM credentials with this client. My team is pretty good at Go.

I know Go can expose rest endpoints that can easily integrate as target groups with AWS ALB. We are currently doing that for our streaming data with great success. However, what I do not know is if we can send "files" as attachments through the AWS ALB, captured by Go as the target group. Once the files are within our Golang/EC2 landscape we can easily add them to S3.

Comment: Yes, you can send POST and PUT requests through an ALB.

Comment: The typical solution to this problem is S3 pre-signed URLs. They will allow upload and are not technically IAM credentials.

Comment: @jordanm Thank you for responding. I did consider pre-signed URL's but S3 pre-signed URL's are pretty limited. I need a solution where a client pushes files to my S3 as soon as they generate data on their end. This activity will be on a long term basis. Also, pre -signed URL's are not very secure. Anyone who gets hold of this URL has all the freedom to use my S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

ALB + EC2 can provide a full RESTful endpoint if you implement it as so.

If you have authn and authz embedded in your program there shouldnt be a problem if your EC2 role has the right permission to access S3.

One caveat to think about is that if you have an ALB backed by a lambda(no matter the language) the payload size limit is 1MB.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest to use SFTP transfer service by AWS, which uses s3 as the backend storage for SFTP.
If client is sending the data from AWS account only then you can share SFTP endpoint as a private link to them, so they can access the SFTP hosted in your AWS account privately using AWS backbone network.

If your clients want to send the data over internet or without AWS account, you can expose the SFTP service in your AWS account with static eip and restrict the inbound traffic with clients public ip.

You would need to manage the SFTP user with private key auth or password based auth

Clients SFTP user which you would be creating in your AWS account would user iam role with trust relationship with SFTP transfer service to upload the data to s3 bucket.

This SFTP solution would give you a channel between your clients and your AWS account.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/create-server-sftp.html